# Conditional CreateAccount Instruction - Associated Token Program

Tags: associated-token-account, spl, associated-token-program

Is there a way to build a transaction that creates an account iff only it doesn't exist. I sometimes run into a race condition between checking that the account exist, broadcasting the transaction and it already existing on chain, which results on the transaction failing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Interesting problem, so assuming you are trying to create an ATA, then this race condition issue has been discussed [here](https://github.com/solana-labs/solana-program-library/issues/2295) and has been solved by implementing a new instruction called [CreateIdempotent](https://github.com/solana-labs/solana-program-library/pull/2883)

The JS binding doesn't exist yet, but you can still call that instruction by crafting it by hand:

```
  const keys = [
    { pubkey: payer, isSigner: true, isWritable: true },
    { pubkey: associatedToken, isSigner: false, isWritable: true },
    { pubkey: owner, isSigner: false, isWritable: false },
    { pubkey: mint, isSigner: false, isWritable: false },
    { pubkey: SystemProgram.programId, isSigner: false, isWritable: false },
    { pubkey: programId, isSigner: false, isWritable: false },
    { pubkey: SYSVAR_RENT_PUBKEY, isSigner: false, isWritable: false },
  ];

  const maybeCreateAtaIx = new TransactionInstruction({
    keys,
    programId: ASSOCIATED_TOKEN_PROGRAM_ID,
    data: Buffer.from(new Uint8Array([1])),
  });

  const tx = new Transaction()
    .add(maybeCreateAtaIx);
    .add(anotherIx); //  yay it goes here even if the ata already exists
```

Comment: Amazing, I wasn't aware of the new instruction. Looks like exactly what I need. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can try to recreate what `getOrCreateAssociatedTokenAccount` is doing

https://github.com/solana-labs/solana-program-library/blob/48fbb5b7c49ea35848442bba470b89331dea2b2b/token/js/src/actions/getOrCreateAssociatedTokenAccount.ts#L35

Something like this:

```
  // get ATA address
  const associatedToken = await getAssociatedTokenAddress(mint, owner.publicKey)

  // create new transaction, you can add instructions before conditionally adding instruction to create token account
  const transaction = new Transaction()

  let account: Account
  try {
    // try to get the token Account
    account = await getAccount(connection, associatedToken)
  } catch (error: unknown) {
    if (
      error instanceof TokenAccountNotFoundError ||
      error instanceof TokenInvalidAccountOwnerError
    ) {
      try {
        // if token Account does not exist, add create instruction to transaction
        transaction.add(
          createAssociatedTokenAccountInstruction(
            owner.publicKey,
            associatedToken,
            owner.publicKey,
            mint
          )
        )
      } catch (error: unknown) {}
    }
  }

  // send transaction, or you can add more instructions to transaction before sending
  const transactionSignature = await sendAndConfirmTransaction(
    connection,
    transaction,
    [owner]
  )
```

Comment: That's what I am doing, but things sometimes change by the time the transaction is broadcasted and if the account went from not existing to existing the transaction fails.